# Windows spotlight in Windows 10 Education

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, windows-spotlight

I have Windows 10 Education installed in my laptop (version 20H2) and I am not able to enable windows spotlight as the lock screen background. The only options in the bar are Picture and Slideshow. There is also a message at the top stating that some of the settings are hidden or managed by my organization. Can anyone tell me how can I enable the spotlight feature or even if this is possible?
(Btw I don't know if this is relevant but I downloaded Windows education as a university student.)

Thank you in advance

[image]

+Update: There is no Personalization option under Windows. Also I am not connected to any AD domain.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows Spotlight can be missing for the following reasons:

- In *Settings > Personalisation > Lock screen* :

  - Ensure that under "Choose which apps show quick status on the lock screen"
    there are no applications listed, remove by click on the app
    and select None at the top of the list
  - Set "Show Windows background picture on the sign-in screen" to Off
  - Remove Cortana from the Lock Screen by clicking
    "Cortana lock screen settings", in the window go to the
    Lock screen section and set to Off
    "Use Cortana even when my device is locked".
- If you have enabled the Windows Hello PIN: Disable it
  in *Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options*,
  click "Windows Hello PIN" and then Remove.
- Try to set the Lock Screen to either Picture or Slideshow,
  reboot and check Spotlight again
- Re-register the Windows Spotlight service using PowerShell
  Run as Administrator with the following commands:

  ```
  Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers |Where-Object {$_.InstallLocation -like "*SystemApps*"} | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
  ```

  When done, change the Personalization setting to
  Windows Spotlight, restart the computer, then check if it works.
- Reset Stoplight settings in the following folder:
  `%USERPROFILE%/AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\Settings`.
  Rename `settings.dat` and `roaming.lock` files, restart the
  computer and test again.
  This might require enabling the option of
  View hidden files and folders.
- Delete all Spotlight files in the folder:
  `%USERPROFILE%/AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets`
- Change the Region settings to the United States
- Wait 24 hours, as when Microsoft Spotlight starts
  it may take that long for fully syncing images.